# Listening to changes in clipboard and sending notification

Tags: android, kotlin

In Kotlin, Android -

I want to listen to changes in the clipboard. If the user copies something, I want the app to send a notification.

Is that possible?
Without showing a permanent notification.
Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android development: How to listen to clipboard changes outside of an APP on Android 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69617515/android-development-how-to-listen-to-clipboard-changes-outside-of-an-app-on-and)

Comment: @Pawel thank you but sadly no. It shows that you have to use custom IME which is not suitable in my case.

Comment: Well, it is the answer just not the one you would like. In short due to security & privacy reasons it's not possible to observe clipboard anymore.